# Can WeasyPrint fit to Paper Size Automatically

Tags: python, html, css, pdf, weasyprint

I used to work for an organization that used Prince XML to generate PDF's of HTML documents.  That organization has since folded, and I no longer have access to that Prince license.  Since I don't have four grand between the couch cushions, I've been attempting to use WeasyPrint to render HTML invoices to PDF.  My HTML & CSS are both quite simple, so Weasy has no problem rendering them accurately, with on caveat.  I cannot get the page to scale down automatically to the paper size like I could in prince using:

```
@page {
prince-shrink-to-fit:auto;
}
```

Does anyone know if Weasy supports any similar command before I rework the CSS of the entire site to generate smaller documents?

Answer (score 4):

By looking around for some ideas to format the pdf rendered by weasyprint, I found this question which might answer your question.

```
@page {
            size: Letter;
            margin: 0in 0.44in 0.2in 0.44in;
    }
```

[WeasyPrint page size wrong. (8.27in x 11.69 in)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831775/weasyprint-page-size-wrong-8-27in-x-11-69-in)

Answer (score 3):

This might help if you're printing a pandas DataFrame

```
from typing import Callable
import pandas as pd
import weasyprint as wp


def html_basic(df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    # Using df.style.render outputs an id in every cell,
    # whilst using df.to_html doesn't.
    return df.style.render()


def write_pdf_autofit(df: pd.DataFrame,
                      preamble: str,
                      fn_df_to_html: Callable[[pd.DataFrame], str]=html_basic
                      ) -> bytes:
    template = f"""<html><body>{preamble}{{table}}</body></html>"""

    # Render on a very long page so that there's no pagination.
    # Width doesn't matter, because overflow is allowed on width.
    mycss = wp.CSS(string=(
        "@page longpage {\n"
        "    size: 210mm 10000mm;\n"
        "}"
        "body {\n"
        "   page: longpage;\n"
        "}\n"
    ))

    # Create a copy of the dataframe with a dummy final column,
    # so that we can get the position of the left side of the
    # dummy column which is the right side of the final real column.
    # Then do a test render to find the positions of stuff.
    df_tmp = df.copy()
    df_tmp['x'] = np.nan
    test_html = template.format(table=fn_df_to_html(df_tmp))
    test_render = wp.HTML(string=test_html).render(stylesheets=[mycss])
    test_page1: wp.Page = test_render.pages[0]

    # I'm not sure why only need to subtract one margin,
    # but seems to work.
    printable_width = test_page1.width - test_page1._page_box.margin_left
    printable_height = 11.7 * 96 - test_page1._page_box.margin_top

    # All the cells in the html rendered DataFrame
    # have an id so are anchors, so just find the
    # max x and y from all the anchors.
    max_x, max_y = map(max, *test_page1.anchors.values())
    zoom_pct = 1
    if max_x > printable_width or max_y > printable_height:
        zoom_pct = min([printable_width / max_x,
                        printable_height / max_y])

    # Increase the page size to fit the table, then
    # we will zoom out the write_pdf to fit standard page size.
    # A4 = 210mm x 297mm
    mycss = wp.CSS(string=(
        "@page scaled {\n"
        f"    size: {210 / zoom_pct}mm {297 / zoom_pct}mm;\n"
        "}"
        "body {\n"
        "   page: scaled;\n"
        "}\n"
    ))

    html = template.format(table=fn_df_to_html(df))
    pdf_bytes = wp.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(zoom=zoom_pct,
                                               stylesheets=[mycss])
    return pdf_bytes


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
    DF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    with open(r'c:\temp\x.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(write_pdf_autofit(DF, ""))
```

Comment: The question is about rendering an HTML document to PDF, nothing to do with Pandas

Answer (score 1):

WeasyPrint does not support anything like this at the moment. [Prince’s documentation](http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/properties/prince-shrink-to-fit/) is pretty sparse on what it does exactly. How is "the width of the content" determined? Given a proper specification of the feature, I could tell how hard it would be to add to WeasyPrint.

By the way, I do not usually watch StackOverflow for WeasyPrint question. Writing to WeasyPrint’s mailing list or issue tracker will get more response.