# Weasyprint pdf does not fit to page

Tags: html, css, pdf, weasyprint

I have an html page with simple css2 rules. All of the content is contained in a div, which is 930px wide. In the browser, this looks as expected, and when printing (from chrome) it fits neatly to the page with a decent font size.

Once I try to create a PDF from this file using weasyprint, the font look much bigger, and the document exceeds the page width.

```
HTML(string=html, base_url=server_base_url).write_pdf(target=target)
```

I'm not really sure how to debug the issue. Weasyprint does not seem to suppose print scaling, which is what I assume chrome is doing. Taking the document, rendering it, and then scaling it to fit on the page.

I tried using the `zoom` parameter of the `write_pdf` method `.write_pdf(target=target, zoom=0.7)`, but it seems to zoom the page size AND the content size, so that is no help, really. I tried combining it with css to make the page bigger. So I zoom down with weasy and scale up with css

```
@page {
    size: XXXin YYYin
}
```

This just ended up looking weird. So where do I go from here?

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried using

```
@page {
    size: Letter;
    margin: 0in 0.44in 0.2in 0.44in;
}
```

You can adjust the margin as you like, but the Letter size should be the standard page size

[page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831775/weasyprint-page-size-wrong-8-27in-x-11-69-in)

Comment: This is an old question now. I believe I endef up solving it by setting a width on the body tag

Comment: @Ross Wilson, I had the same problem as Eldamir but in my case passing the page parameters you mentiones through the stylesheets weasyprint argument has not worked. Anything else I could try? My printed documented is still exceeding the page in size. Eldemir, if you could remember the solution and post it here it would be really helpful too!

Comment: @fernandosjp I'm not sure if this is helpful, but it seems like I also had to limit the width of the body element (mine is currently set to 600px but it could probably be bigger depending on the margins you want). If I set it really high, then the information on the pdf will go off the standard size page.